# Are the cards a one-time use?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

In Rise of the Tomb Raider, when you buy cards from the store, are they a one-time use or do they have infinite uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GameRant](https://gamerant.com/rise-of-tomb-raider-microtransactions-614/):

> The foil cards are an interesting development in Rise of the Tomb Raider‘s microtransaction model. Normal cards disappear after being used in-game, but foils are permanent.

[This EuroGamer article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2015-10-08-rise-of-the-tomb-raider-microtransactions-detailed) concurs with this statement:

> Packs contain common cards, which can be used a single time, and foil cards, which can be used repeatedly.

From the [Expedition Cards wikia page](https://www.wikiraider.com/index.php/Expedition_Cards):

> Generally speaking, five star cards are foil and as such can be used infinite times, **but it's worth noting that outfit and weapon cards also are permanent, regardless of their individual rarity.** Foil cards are easily distinguished by their gold borders and distinct shine in the card selection screen.

Comment: What is the difference between foil and non-foil, such as which cards are and which aren't? You don't need a source for this question.

Comment: From [here](https://www.wikiraider.com/index.php/Expedition_Cards) (sorry, I needed a source for this :p), it looks like in general, 5-star cards will be foil.  Also, that weapon and outfit cards are always permanent. (I just added this to my answer) Foil cards will have gold borders and shine in the menu, though, if you are looking for a visual indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Foil cards have unlimited uses, while non-foil cards are single use only.